# CollegeScorecard.gov SAT & ACT requirements

Tags: collegescorecard

From CollegeScorecard.gov, how can I get data about whether SAT is required, optional or not used at all? We are using the API.

There's a section with this info. It's titled "Test Scores" under the larger header "Test Scores & Acceptance"

California State University-Sacramento has an acceptance rate of 94%. California State University-Sacramento does not require admission test scores (SAT/ACT) during the application process and does not recommend that students provide them.

Harvard University has an acceptance rate of 4%. Harvard University considers admission test scores (SAT/ACT) during the application process, but does not require them. Students who were admitted to Harvard University and enrolled typically had admission test scores in these ranges.

University of North Alabama has an acceptance rate of 90%. University of North Alabama recommends students provide admission test scores (SAT/ACT), during the application process.

Answer (score 0):

This is available in the IPEDS data set (a little harder to access): https://nces.ed.gov/ipeds/use-the-data/survey-components/6/admissions